# Switching Regulator[AP65211A] Issues: Higher Voltage then expected at minimal load, drops to 0 with small load

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I normally just use linear regulators in my designs and this is why...

Switching Regulator in question: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP65211A.pdf

Circuit:
[image]
Board Layout:
[image]

The problem I am having is under a 10K load the output is ~10V and is quite noisy(Sorry I will post scope images later if we can't solve this without it, and with a 47-ohm load it drops to 0.8V. I don't see what I could have done wrong. I have removed all other parts from the board except the regulator components.

DK part #s for all the parts used:

- C6: 732-7526-1-ND
- C7: 732-7494-1-ND
- C8: 732-7539-1-ND
- L1: 587-3143-1-ND
- C9: 732-7539-1-ND
- C10: 732-7511-1-ND
- R2: RMCF0402JT100KCT-ND
- R3: RMCF0402JT75K0CT-ND
- R4: RC0402FR-0778K7L
- R5: YAG2984CT-ND

Right now I am thinking its C8 needs to be bigger, or I have selected a very bad inductor?

Thanks,
Kyle

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I should delete this one out of shame, or leave it here for anyone else to learn from...

I didn't actually ground the GND rail on that sub-sheet... So it was left floating, after running a jumper it was all good.

Larger input and output caps are also needed uF instead of nF